# Style individual RadioButtonList ListItem

Tags: asp.net, html, css, radiobuttonlist

I know that you can assign a class to the generated `table` by using `CssClass` on the `RadioButtonList` but I need to be able to style the generated `<td>`'s individually.

Easy with JQuery but I'd much rather not have to resort to that.

Adding `cssClass="myClass"` to the `ListItem` results in the following broken HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span cssclass="some_class"> // Well this is rubbish!
                    <input id="myRadioInput" type="radio" name="myRadioInput" value="myValue" >
                    <label for="myRadioInput">myLabel</label>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="myRadioInput2" type="radio" name="myRadioInput2" value="myValue2">
                <label for="myRadioInput2">myLabel2</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So my question is: Is it actually posible to either assign a class or apply inline styling to the generated `<td>`'s **INDIVIDUALLY**?

**PLEASE NOTE**
This is a question about ASP.NET. Answers that simply tell me how to style HTML elements are not answering the question.

Comment: Do you want to set styling to each td seperately or one css class for all of the tds?

Comment: Individually, sorry I'll update the question...

Comment: Are you creating the control or list items dynamically in your code behind?

Comment: No, it's just a straight up control in the .aspx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style all the td's you could add the CSS like so...

```
 #myTable td{
        color:Red;
    }
```

Other than that (if you wanted different styles for each td) jQuery would be the only way to add classes to those generated td's.

```
$('#myTable td:eq(0)').addClass('td1');
$('#myTable td:eq(1)').addClass('td2');
...
```

OR

```
$.each($('#myTable td'), function(i){
   $(this).addClass('td'+i);
});
```

This is one of the reasons I dislike ASP.NET controls with all the extra markup you have no control of through the properties panel.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant "style the td's individually". My mistake.

Comment: JQuery is your friend in this case because Microsoft hates you... I updated my post with jQuery solutions

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do it with JQuery. I was hoping I was missing something obvious.

Comment: ya I don't think you're missing anything... it's just the nature of the .NET controls.  Which is why I have been steering away from them and just using the basic HTML controls, because hey thats what the ASP.NET controls create anyways

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but ended up using JQuery do I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in code (e.g. if you need to dynamically adjust the style based on complicated logic) you can set the `style` attribute on the ListItem (setting the `class` attribute might work as well but if your ListItem is disabled, asp.net will override it with a special aspNetDisabled class):

```
item.Attributes["style"] = "color: lightgray; font-style: italic;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="yourcssclassname"></td>
    <td class="yourcssclassname2></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
  .yourcssclassname
  {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .yourcssclassname2
  {
    padding: 15px;
  }
</style>
```

or you can

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:10px;"></td>
    <td style="padding:15px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think he is using the ASP.NET RadioButtonList control which automatically generates the table markup and the poster has no control over the table markup.

Comment: I need to assign the classes with the RadioButtonList (asp.net). Please re-read the Q

Comment: Can it have a numeric value attached to it?

Answer (score 0):

You are so close to the solution. Add class attribute instead of cssclass on the items for individual styling. This will add a `span` tag surrendering the `input` and `label` tags with the right class.

```
<style>
    .radiobuttonlist .red       { display: block; background-color: red; }
</style>    

<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" CssClass="radiobuttonlist">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item2" Value="2" class="red" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item3" Value="3" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I just copy pasted the code I wrote and it works fine, exactly what the OP asked about.

Answer (score -1):

You can target the input elements and labels with:

```
input[type="radio"] { margin-right:10px; }
input[type="radio"] + label { color:red; }
```

If you had a class on the table, you could add that to be more explicit. Should be backwards compatible to IE7.

Comment: He wants to style them indivdually.